# Dereferencing pointer to char pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference, strdup

I have the following code:

```
char **ptr;
*ptr=strdup("This is a pointer");
cout<<*ptr<<endl;
```

When I try to execute it I get segfault at the `cout` instruction. If I do instead

```
char *ptr;
ptr=strdup("This is a pointer");
cout<<ptr<<endl;
```

Everything works correctly. What causes the problem and what is the workararound? I am not looking for solutions of the type "Use strings".

Comment: What is it that you think `char **ptr` does exactly?

Comment: Hint: Why does `int *ptr; *ptr = 5; cout << *ptr << endl;` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char **ptr; //I have a pointer to pointer to char
*ptr = ...; //I dereference the pointer I never initialized and, wait...
```

`ptr` was never initialized to point to anything. When you dereference and assign to it, you're getting undefined behavior. Either just don't use `**` pointers when you don't need them, or initialize `ptr`.

```
char** ptr = new char*(strdup("where did my rubber duck go"));
```

Comment: Note that `(strdup("where did my rubber duck go"))` isn't necessary for *allocating* the `char*` - here James is allocating and initializing it at the same time.